# Difference between tf.train.Checkpoint and tf.train.Saver

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, eager-execution

I found there are different ways to save/restore models and variables in `Tensorflow`. These ways including:

- [tf.saved_model.simple_save](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/simple_save)
- [tf.train.Checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint)
- [tf.train.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver)

In tensorflow's documentations, I found some differences between them:

1. `tf.saved_model` is a thin wrapper around `tf.train.Saver`
2. `tf.train.Checkpoint` support eager execution but `tf.train.Saver` **not**.
3. `tf.train.Checkpoint` not creating `.meta` file but still can load graph structure (here is a big question! how it can do that?)

How `tf.train.Checkpoint` can load graph without `.meta` file? or more generally What is the difference between `tf.train.Saver` and `tf.train.Checkpoint`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Tensorflow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint):

> `Checkpoint.save` and `Checkpoint.restore` write and read object-based
>   checkpoints, in contrast to `tf.train.Saver` which writes and reads
>   variable.name based checkpoints. Object-based checkpointing saves a
>   graph of dependencies between Python objects (Layers, Optimizers,
>   Variables, etc.) with named edges, and this graph is used to match
>   variables when restoring a checkpoint. It can be more robust to
>   changes in the Python program, and helps to support restore-on-create
>   for variables when executing eagerly. **Prefer `tf.train.Checkpoint` over
>   `tf.train.Saver` for new code**.